# How to sort array sets in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I need a help with the following:

I have 1 array set and another an array list: a = [132,175] and b = [132,132,132,175,175].

I want to sort these two sets so that the end result will look like:

132 =>[132,132,132]

175 =>[175,175]

```
for i in a
  for c in b
    if i == c
      puts c.inspect
    end
  end
  puts 'Break'
end
```

output I get:

```
132
132
132
Break
175
175
Break
```

I have tried many different ways but I could not get the results I wanted.
Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by an array set? Those are just arrays. What is `132 --->[132,132,132]`?

Comment: What is `e`? ...........

Comment: I suggest you edit to refer to `a` and `b` merely as "arrays", and if it is a hash you want to produce, say so, and show it: `{132=>[132, 132, 132], 175=>[175, 175]}`.  Don't say you'll be sorting the two arrays, as that may not be necessary. When asking questions it always helpful to give a short, carefully-constructed example (assuming the question lends itself to that), and when you do, always show the desired result as a valid Ruby expression. Test them first with IRB and then copy and paste. IRB would not accept `132 --->[132,132,132]`, so don't say that.

Comment: @sawa, `e` is the base for natural logarithms.  It is an irrational and transcendental constant equal to approximately 2.718281828. (I'm taking your question literally, as you have been known to do of others. :-) .)

Comment: @CarySwoveland A Ruby constant has to be capitalized. Where in RDoc is it defined that `e` express the base of natural logarithm? All I could find was `Math::E`.

Comment: @sawa I thought you were just asking a general questions, not specifically about Ruby, but come to think of it, that would be against the rules, rules that you have been sworn to uphold, so I guess I shouldn't have made that assumption. Yes, what is `e`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I have no idea what you are writing about. I am mentining the `e` in the OP's code.

Comment: Hi Gary, sorry, it is one of those things when i get very, very tired, i, sometimes, produce weird things. So, apologies for that :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, Ruby will not use "for...in" statement to make it, it is not "Ruby way". "each", "map" or "inject" method is the better choice.

```
2.1.2 :046 > a = [132,175]
=> [132, 175]
2.1.2 :047 > b = [132,132,132,175,175]
=> [132, 132, 132, 175, 175]
2.1.2 :048 > a.inject({}) {|r,e| r.merge({e => b.select{ |v| v == e}})}
=> {132=>[132, 132, 132], 175=>[175, 175]}
```

a little shorter

```
2.1.2 :050 > a.inject({}) {|r,e| r.merge({e => [e] * b.count(e)})}
=> {132=>[132, 132, 132], 175=>[175, 175]}
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I am working on Ruby on Rails project. I need to iterate through records. Set 'a' represents members id and set 'b' represent items belonging to members.I need to use it in the way I described in my original question. I am very thankful that you gave me an idea how to re-adjust my coding.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way among many:

```
a = [132,175] 
b = [132,132,132,175,175]

a.each_with_object({}) { |e,h| h[e] = [e]*b.count(e) }
  #=> {132=>[132, 132, 132], 175=>[175, 175]}
```

Comment: Sorry Gary, I meant 'a' is an array set and 'b' is an array. I was so tired writing the question, that I thought my fellow programmers will understand my question even as bad as this.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.

First, the logic for selecting which items end up in the result is not clear. So, I'll assume that you want the items selected from the `b` array corresponding to the items of the `a` array.

Second, it's not clear if by "result" you mean *output* or an *object* (like a hash).  So, I'll assume you want an object result.

```
def select_keys keys, array
  res = {}
  keys.each {|key| res[key] = array.select {|v| v == key}}
  res
end

a
=> [132, 175]
b
=> [132, 132, 132, 175, 175]
select_keys a, b
=> {132=>[132, 132, 132], 175=>[175, 175]}
```

If you want `select_keys` to operate as an Array method, try this:

```
class Array
  def select_keys array
    res = {}
    self.each {|key| res[key] = array.select {|v| v == key}}
    res
  end
end

a.select_keys b
=> {132=>[132, 132, 132], 175=>[175, 175]}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will think it through.

Answer (score 0):

```
b = [132,132,132,175,175]
p b.group_by{|el| el} # => {132=>[132, 132, 132], 175=>[175, 175]}
```